# Shorten for-loops into one

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop, short, code-readability

is it possible to shorten these three for loops into one
the code works absolutely fine, I just want to know if there is a possibility to shorten these three for loops into one for exercising reasons and also for code-readability

```js
let board_coord = []

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  board_coord.push({
    x: i * 166,
    y: 0
  })
}
for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  board_coord.push({
    x: j * 166,
    y: 166
  })
}
for (let k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
  board_coord.push({
    x: k * 166,
    y: 332
  })
}

console.log(board_coord)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean a single top level loop, you could use a nested loop:

```js
const SIZE = 166;
let boardCoord = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        boardCoord.push({ x: SIZE * j, y: SIZE * i });
    }
}
```

I don't think a single loop overall would be any more readable than this.

Comment: yes thats exactly what i was thinking of, I just couldnt see it

Answer (score 2):

A single loop would require a little math. (see: [Remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) and [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor))

```js
const boardCoord = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  boardCoord.push({
    x: (i % 3) * 166,
    y: Math.floor(i / 3) * 166
  })
}

console.log(boardCoord)
```

Or generalized...

```js
const WIDTH = 3;
const HEIGHT = 3;
const SCALE = 166;

const boardCoord = [];
for (let i = 0; i < WIDTH * HEIGHT; i++) {
  boardCoord.push({
    x: (i % WIDTH) * SCALE,
    y: Math.floor(i / WIDTH) * SCALE
  })
}

console.log(boardCoord)
```

But it's not necessarily more readable than a nested loop which can also be generalized.

```js
const COLS = 3;
const ROWS = 3;
const SCALE = 166;

const boardCoord = [];
for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
  for (let col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
    boardCoord.push({ x: SCALE * col, y: SCALE * row });
  }
}
console.log(boardCoord)
```